# horizontal scroll bar for gallery

Tags: html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

im really pulling my hair out with this one. ive sat here for about 5+hours plus trying to figure it out and trial/error the possibilities.
i have a central positioned page with a fixed width and i want to set a space in the middle for a gallery that horizontally scrolls. this is proving a big problem.

this is my css:

```
#container {
 height: 800px;
 width: 950px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: visible;
}
#header {
 background-image: url(images/header.gif);
 height: 155px;
 width: 950px;
}
#main {
 height: 417px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 width: auto;
 background-color: #000;
 float: left;
 /* [disabled]white-space: nowrap; */
 /* [disabled]overflow: scroll; */
}
#footer {
 background-image: url(images/footer.gif);
 height: 128px;
 width: 950px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 clear: both;
}
.text {
 font-family: "Arial Narrow", Futura-Book, sans-serif;
 font-size: 70%;
 width: 14px;
}
.pics {
 padding-left: 10px;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 10px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

i am a newb and trying so hard to learn, but i really cant figure this out. i dont want a table. i can create a vertically scrolling box, but thats not what i want.

please all help very much appreciated

thanks

Comment: even though i did not understand the problem. it might be you are using width: auto, overflow-x: scroll and float together, this seems problematic. you must set a width in this situation

Comment: Please us jsfiddle.net to put both html markup and css and paste the link here so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to say that I don't think float works that way. Any element with a left or right float *will* override your settings and make room for itself on the next line.

To fix that, I took away the float property for the images and gave their container a *white-space:nowrap;*

You can see what I did with the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mendota/w9dvp/2/), in action.

This is the CSS:

```
#footer {
    white-space: nowrap;
    float:left;
    background-color:grey;
    max-height: 128px;
    width:950px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: scroll;
    clear: both;
}
.pics {
    height:98px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    float:;
    overflow-x:;
    overflow-y:;
}
```

And here's the HTML I used to force an overflow situation:

```
<p id="footer">

    <img class="pics" alt="Picture 1" title="Banana stand? hahaha" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx2IF.jpg" />
    <img class="pics" alt="Picture 2" title="That's pretty witty" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gwbn.jpg" />
    <img class="pics" alt="Picture 3" title="TV time" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYa29.png" />
    <img class="pics" alt="Picture 1" title="Banana stand? hahaha" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx2IF.jpg" />
    <img class="pics" alt="Picture 2" title="That's pretty witty" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gwbn.jpg" />
    <img class="pics" alt="Picture 3" title="TV time" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYa29.png" /><img class="pics" alt="Picture 1" title="Banana stand? hahaha" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx2IF.jpg" />
    <img class="pics" alt="Picture 2" title="That's pretty witty" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gwbn.jpg" />
    <img class="pics" alt="Picture 3" title="TV time" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYa29.png" />

</p>
```

The footer paragraph is told to be a certain width, to use a scrollbar for overflow, *and* to disallow line breaks. So, the pictures are forced to behave *as if* they're floating, since they're not allowed to drop to the next line.

Hope this helps someone; I know I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a "width" to #main

```
#main {
 height: 417px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 width: auto;
 background-color: #000;
 float: left;
 width:950px;

}
```